# Pictures are very bright when using the flash

Tags: iphone, photos, camera, case

Every time when I take a picture or video with flash, it turns out very, very bright on my iPhone 6s. Especially at night the glare is so bad you really can’t see anything.

Comment: Do you have it in a case? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Some cases do not leave enough of an opening around the flash LEDs. The edges of the case then reflect light from the flash onto the camera sensor, resulting in a lot of glare during flash photography and video recording.

The only solution is to not use that case while using your camera’s flash. It would be best to simply switch to a different case with a wider/better-designed rear camera opening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to not make the flash so bright on your iPhone, but you could use a third-party camera app on the App Store, like Camera+, to control exposure and other settings.